# Laravel Livewire Model - public variable state

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am using Livewire to create a form which databinds to the model like this, notice `<select/>` has `multiple` attribute:

```
@php
  $items = ['bag','hat','mug','stickers'];
@endphp
<select wire:model="extra" multiple > 
  <option disabled value="select" >Select</option> 
  @foreach ($items as $item)
    <option value="{{$item}}" >{{$item}}</option> 
  @endforeach
</select>
```

and the model class has a var on top:

```
public $extra = [''];
```

I would like to select multiple `<option/>` with just a click, currently you have to use the keyboard [command] + click.

I am trying to add logic in the model class but state of `public $extra = [''];` is an issue.

example:

```
<option value="{{$item}}" wire:click="buildArr('{{$item}}')">{{$item}}</option>
```

then from model, `$this->extra[]` does not build on the array but rather refreshes and returns the last `<option/>` clicked:

```
public function buildArr($item){
  $this->extra[]= $item;
}
```

How can I allow 1 click to build on this array?  Do I need AlpineJS?

Answer (score 0):

the answer to my problem was here https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/alpine-js#interacting-with-livewire-from-alpine
using: `$wire.myMethod()` from blade.